# reducing output feature number of pretraind mode weight in keras

Tags: python, keras

I want extract 1000 image features using pretrained Xception model.
but xception models last layer(avg_pool) give 2048 features.
Can i reduce final output feature number without additional training?
I want image features before the softmax not predcition result.

```
base_model = xception.Xception(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')    
base_model.summary()
self.model = Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('avg_pool').output)
```

Answer (score 0):

This model was trained to produce embeddings in 2048-dimensional space to the classifier after it. There is no sense in trying to reduce the dimensionality of the embedding space, unless you are combining very complex and inflexible models. If you are just doing simple transfer learning with no memory constraints, just snap your new classifier (extra layers) on top of it, and retrain after freezing (or not) all layers in the original Xception. That should work regardless of Xception output_shape. See the [keras docs](https://keras.io/applications/).

That said, if you REALLY need to reduce dimensionality to 1000-d, you will need a method that preserves (or at least tries to preserve) the original topology of the embedding space, otherwise your model will not benefit at all from transfer learning. Take a look at [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html), [SVD](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html), or [T-SNE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html).